# Pulling a certain date from datetime column python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How do you pull a certain date from a datetime column. I have been using this

```
df.loc[(df['column name'] == 'date')]
```

But it cannot find the date although it is in the df.

Answer (score 1):

Your datetime column has probably smaller granularity than just the date(year,month,day), the default in pandas is nanoseconds(ns) but it could also be just seconds in your case, depending on the data source. You can see the dtype by accessing df.column.dtype yourself, and it also helps with the case when you column isnt actually of datetime dtype, in which case you need to cast it to datetime first.

And '2001-15-12' is not equal to '2001-15-12 18:36:45:2242'
Neither '2001-15-12'  to '2001-15-12 18:36:45'

If you only need dates, set the datetime colum to just the date like this, using the .dt accesor for datetime segments:

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].dt.date
```

Then you'll be able to access

```
df.loc[(df['column name'] == 'date')] #using just the year, month and date in the format above.
```